# Can I have my class inherit from another class at run-time?

Tags: c#, inheritance, azure-table-storage

I have a class (person) that is a model in my MVVM application. I want to save this class to Azure Table Storage. To save to Azure Table Storage, you need to derive from a class called TableServiceEntity. I'd prefer to not clutter my nice class with attributes meant for storage (seems like a good idea in considering separation of concerns).

Can I somehow have my class derive from TableServiceEntity at run-time, inside the methods that receive the object as a parameter and persist it to storage? That would let my class stay clean of the storage attributes, but still let me save it to Table Storage.

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: You could always dig into `System.Reflection.Emit`, but I think that creating a new type at runtime probably isn't the best approach.

Comment: I either wouldn't suggest using Reflection. It takes a lot out of your application performance wise

Comment: @Amit Not reflection, code emission.  This namespace contains types you can use to actually create new types at runtime, on-the-fly.  You emit IL to create methods, which are then JIT-compiled just like any other type.  Once you are done creating a type with this API, it will perform exactly the same as if it were compiled by the C# compiler.

Comment: @cdhowie, yes i meant emission by pointing to namespace, my bad should have made it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simulate something like it using a DynamicObject or [Castle Proxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=DynamicProxy&NS=Tools&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Instead of saving Person to azure, you could create an AzureEntity using one of those techniques, and generate an object that has all the same properties as Person, yet it inherits from TableServiceEntity.

The TableServiceEntity thing, is only done for ease of use... You could get your hands on the storage client library source code (which is published somewhere around git hub or codeplex as far as I remember), and modify it to work without using the TableServiceEntity thing.

**Update for comment:** 
In your case you can use both... The difference is that in expando object you define the object by extension, while the dynamic object is defined by comprehension. Dynamic object is a little more powerful (and more complex), but you don't need any of that in this case.
BTW: The Castle Proxy is pretty similar to the dynamic object approach, but it generates a lot of the code at runtime, so it'll probably achieve a far better performance than either the dynamic object, or the expando object.

**Further update:**
You can make expando object implement an interface like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/03/dynamicduck-duck-typing-in-a-dynamic-world.aspx).

Comment: Ahh, ok. I was just asking dasblinkenlight about using an Expando object - I'm not very familiar with the DLR but thought there might be something there. So you think I should look more toward DynamicObject than Expando object?

Comment: That's perfect - except I think I'm tripped up by the fact that you don't just need the properties you inherit from TableServiceEntity to save to the Azure Tables, your class also needs to be decorated with this attribute: [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]. There's no way to give an expando object an attribute, is there?

Comment: Great, Thanks! That's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change inheritance at runtime.

What you can do is map from your domain object to a data storage object derived from TableServiceEntity using a tool such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

One of the benefits of O/R Mappers like Entity Framework Code First or NHibernate is that they do not force you to derive from a special base class.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no: inheritance in C# is a compile-time concept, so your object must inherit from its base class at compile time.

As far as the "cluttering your code with attributes meant for storage" goes, partial classes could very much help: put storage-related attributes in a separate file, and your code will look clean again.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys - but just to plumb every possibility - is there anything in the DLR, like the expando object, that would let me add the necessary attributes to the class when I go to save it? Or could I take an expando object as a parameter in the method that persists to storage, and have the expando object inherit the TableServiceEntity class? The DLR is a vague concept for me at this point, but I had been looking into it for this reason.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz You cannot inherit expando object and table service entity at the same time, but you can implement the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface that expando object implements, and forward calls to an embedded expando object. This is hardly an improvement over inheriting at compile time, though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be simpler to just create a `PersonTableServiceEntity` class and a static method to translate between your `Person` entity and the `PersonTableServiceEntity`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer-- NO. It's all done at compile time in c#. Srry

Answer (score 1):

No idea at all if that's possible, but it doesn't strike me as likely.
Just create a PersonStorage class to inherit TableServiceEntity with a single Person instance?